# UiwebView resize based on content

Tags: uiwebview, height

Am creating a UIWebView like this

```
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    NSString *s=[arrayWithTwoStrings objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    self.webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.webView.opaque=NO;
    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:s baseURL:nil];
    self.webView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:FALSE];
    [self.webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self.webView sizeToFit];
    CGFloat totalHeight = self.webView.frame.origin.y+self.webView.frame.size.height+30;
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, totalHeight)];
```

am not fitting webview height based on content .

i have tried the some techniques on search but that couldnot work

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to adjust the height of the web view so that user does not need to scroll vertically within the web view, you need to get the height after the HTML string is loaded into the web view.

Implement the delegate of the web view when the loading of the HTML string is finished and calculate the height based on the scroll view height:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    aWebView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(aWebView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(aWebView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(aWebView.frame), aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```